# Как к созданному из JSON строки объекту добавить новое поле

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте! Имеется файл objectT.txt содержащий JSON строку:

```
{
"noData":false,
"activity_empty":"No Data",
"one":[
    {"Id":"111222", "image_visible":true, "image":"ic_new.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700",     "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk,

IL", "tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",    "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"},
    {"Id":"222222", "image_visible":false, "image":"ic_new.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700",    "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk,

IL", "tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",    "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"}    
     ]
}
```

затем эту строку переводим в объект objectT, как добавить НОВОЕ поле в объекте objectT, как добавить НОВОЕ поле в массив one объекта objectT (objectT.one), может не нужно переводить строку в объект, а производить манипуляции с ней?

```
           jQuery.get('objectT.txt', {} ,function(obj)
            {
            objectT = obj;
            objectT = JSON.parse(objectT); 
            //Добавление к objectT нового поля   
            //Добавление к objectT.one нового поля               
            var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(objectT);                
            jQuery('#id-container').append( myJSONText );
            }, 'text')
```

Что бы получилось следующее:

```
 {
    "noData":false,
    "activity_empty":"No Data",
    "NEW_FIELD":"NEW_FIELD",
    "NEW_FIELD":"NEW_FIELD",
    "one":[
        {"NEW_FIELD":"NEW_FIELD", "Id":"111222", "image_visible":true, "image":"ic_new.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700",     "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk,

    IL", "tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",    "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"},
        {"NEW_FIELD":"NEW_FIELD", "Id":"222222", "image_visible":false, "image":"ic_new.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700",    "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk,

    IL", "tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",    "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"}    
         ]
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно так:

```
objectT.NEW_FIELD = 'NEW_FIELD';
```

или так:

```
objectT['NEW_FIELD'] = 'NEW_FIELD';
```